# Get raw json or dictionary in .NET API

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to get a non-model bound set of json data in a route in a .NET WebAPI. The backstory is that I'd like to update a few fields, dependent on what's passed in, instead of overwriting a whole object. So, the request would look like this:

```
path: ./api/user/2    PUT
json: { "email":"doodly@test.com"}
```

Now, in the scaffolded method for PUT, this would overwrite user of id=2 with the new email and a bunch of null values for the other columns. This is because the json is auto-bound to a model and when that object is created, the non-present values are null.

I could simply check for null in the passed object and only update non-null fields, but then if someone did the below, it would break:

```
json: { "email":"doodly@test.com", "phone":null }
```

In this case, the phone wouldn't get nullify when it should, as it would get skipped over. So, I need to get the json as-is to know how and what to update on the record of the given id. How can I do this?

Comment: Have different actions for different types of update?

Comment: @DixonD Can you please elaborate? I'm uncertain how one would approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the raw JSON, or would a [`JObject`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) work for you?

```
public void Put([FromBody] JObject jsonData)
{
    JToken token;
    if (jsonData.TryGetValue("phone", out token))
    {
        var value = (string)token;
        if (value == null)
        {
            // phone property exists but has null value
        }
        else
        {
            // phone property exists and has non-null value
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // phone property does not exist
    }
}
```

Comment: I've never worked with JObjects. What's the format on accessing the properties in this way?

Comment: @steven: I've updated my answer to show how you might use `JObject`. (Obviously you could extract this into a helper and/or extension method in order to keep your action/controller code clean and readable.)